# How to pass the hyperlink string from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks "UI.xlsm" and "Gas_Insulated_MV_Circuit.xlsm", in the first workbook (UI.xlsm) i ave maintained a list of hyperlinks in a particular column, on click of the link it will take me to a respective other workbooks.

The task is to capture the text of the clicked hyperlink from "UI.xlsm" workbook and i have to use the same value in "Gas_Insulated_MV_Circuit.xlsm"

Below is the code from UI.xlsm workbook where I am capturing the clicked hyperlink cell text and storing it as string

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim BR as String
    BR = Target.Range.Text  'Here i'm storing the clicked cell text 
End Sub
```

Now i need to use the BR string value in another workbook "Gas_Insulated_MV_Circuit.xlsm"

```
Public BR as String   ' I have declared BR as a public variable
  Private Sub CommandButton27_Click()
  Dim WbUI as Workbook
  Dim WsUI as Worksheet
  Dim File1 as string


  Set WbUI = Workbooks ("UI.xlsm")
  Set WsUI = WbUI.Sheets("Sheet1")

  File1 = BR ' I want something like this, where i can assign BR value from                        
                UI.xlsm workbook to File 1 of the current workbook

End Sub
```

Could anyone kindly help me in achieving it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a defined name (e.g. **myBR**) in the **UI.xlsm** workbook with `=Sheet1!A1` as the *Refers to:*. With that defined name 'seeded', I changed your [Worksheet.FollowHyperlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838843.aspx) event macro to,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
        ThisWorkbook.Names("myBR").RefersToR1C1 = _
          Chr(61) & Chr(34) & Target.Range.Text & Chr(34)
End Sub
```

In the **Gas_Insulated_MV_Circuit.xlsm** workbook, I can retrieve the most recently clicked hyperlink's cell text (i.e. [TextToDisplay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx) property) with,

```
=UI.xlsm!myBR
```

With both workbooks open, the cell value changes were immediate. Assignment to a string or integer variable in VBA should be no problem.

Comment: what is myBR? is it a cell text at A1 ?

Comment: Formulas ► Defined Names ► Name Manager ► Add ► Name: **myBR**, Scope: **Workbook**, Refers to: **=Sheet1!A1**. That creates a named range called **myBR** that can be changed later with the Worksheet_FollowHyperlink event macro.